# Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to submit a Form and I am getting this error. It seems to originate from my layout file as I have two different partial views rendered inside the layout for several purposes. Example:

```
 @{Html.RenderAction("_MenuSearch", "Platform");}
```

This is inside my layout, and the Platform controller receives and manages certain data with this. I can post to it without issue. The main problem happens when I submit a form with another Model. I get this:

> Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. 
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about 
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: 
>   Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.

I need to have these partial views inside my layout, yet I cannot submit other forms. What can I do?

EDIT: MenuSearch Method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult _MenuSearch()
    {
        LayoutViewModel viewModel = new LayoutViewModel();
        return PartialView(viewModel);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _MenuSearch(LayoutViewModel viewModel)
    {

        Guid? memberKey = _memberInfoService.GetMemberId(viewModel.MemberIdentifier);
        if (memberKey == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("NoResults", "Platform");
        }
        else
        {
            Session["MemberFound"] = true;
            Session["MemberGuid"] = memberKey;
            return RedirectToAction("MemberDisplay/" + memberKey.ToString(), "Platform");

        }
```

Comment: Show your methods (the message is self explanatory - your trying to redirect in a method that is decorated with `[ChildActionOnly]`

Comment: I added the Method for _MenuSearch in this case.

Comment: @StephenMuecke not necessarily decorated - it can be just called from the view as child action. Looking at call stack when `RedirectToAction` is called should clarify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Method" is taken into account when searching for child actions - so when you handle POST request and in you view calling `Html.RenderAction("_MenuSearch", "Platform");` than `public ActionResult _MenuSearch(LayoutViewModel viewModel)` will be picked since it is marked with `HttpPost`.

It is generally safe to have special separate set of actions marked with `ChildAction` attribute to avoid such cases.

Comment: Hi Alexei. I added the attribute, but I do need to post to that method to get several results. If i add the attribute then it will tell me it can only be accessed through ChildActions

Comment: @LordRelix - "*separate set* of actions marked with ChildAction attribute".